# Issue with online logged users in my Django application

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-users

As always, I'm trying to improve my `Django application` and I would like to create a Django module which could `display all logged users`.

This is my model class `LoggedUser` :

```
class LoggedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def login_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        LoggedUser(user=user).save()

    def logout_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        try:
            u = LoggedUser.objects.get(user=user)
            u.delete()
        except LoggedUser.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    user_logged_in.connect(login_user)
    user_logged_out.connect(logout_user)
```

Then, I have in my view :

```
def ConnectedUsers(request) :

    logged_users=[user.user for user in LoggedUser.objects.all()]
    print logged_users

    context = {
        "logged_users":logged_users,
    }

    return render(request, "UtilisateursConnectes.html", context)
```

The `print query` returns : `[]`

And a very simple template just in order to display logged users :

```
{% block content %}

List of logged users :

    {% for users in logged_users %} 
        <li>{{ users }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

The problem is : When I try to connect different account on my software, the table `LoggedUser` is still empty. Do I make a mistake in my script ?

Comment: Why are your signal connects inside of model definition

Comment: @iklinac It should be set in my view function ?

Comment: This is guesswork at the best but remove indentation before them :) so that they are outside of class

Comment: But if they are outside of class, `user_logged_in` will be not defined ?

Comment: functions also should be outside of model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your connects are not connected to Django signals

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in, user_logged_out  

class LoggedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

def login_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        LoggedUser(user=user).save()

def logout_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        try:
            u = LoggedUser.objects.get(user=user)
            u.delete()
        except LoggedUser.DoesNotExist:
            pass

user_logged_in.connect(login_user)
user_logged_out.connect(logout_user)
```

Comment: I have to import Django signal ? Because `user_logged_in` is not defined.